# Future Builder not rendering data table

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-future

in want create table from api response.i created data table using future builder. The future builder fires api twice not not return any data

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 const HomeScreen({super.key});
 
 @override
 State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}
 
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: FutureBuilder(
       future: unpaid(),
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.hasData) {
           return Container(
               padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
               child:
                   Dataclass(datalist: snapshot.data as List<UnpaidDetails>));
         } else {
           return Container(
 
               // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
               // child: Dataclass(
               //     datalist: snapshot.data as List<UnpaidDetails>)
               );
         }
       },
     ),
   );
 }
 
 Future<String?> getToken() async {
   final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   return prefs.getString('token');
 }
 
 Future<List<UnpaidDetails>> unpaid() async {
   String? token = await getToken();
 
   final response = await http.get(
       Uri.parse('https://test.url/api/unpaid'),
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
       });
 
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
     List jsonResponse = result["UnpaidDetails"] as List;
 
     return jsonResponse.map((e) => UnpaidDetails.fromJson(e)).toList();
   } else {
     throw Exception('Failed to update album.');
   }
 }
}
 
class Dataclass extends StatefulWidget {
 Dataclass({Key? key, required List<UnpaidDetails> this.datalist})
     : super(key: key);
 List<UnpaidDetails> datalist;
 @override
 DataclassState createState() {
   return DataclassState();
 }
}
 
class DataclassState extends State<Dataclass> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) 
  return SingleChildScrollView(
       scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
       child: FittedBox(
           child: DataTable(
         sortColumnIndex: 1,
         showCheckboxColumn: false,
         border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.0),
         columns: const [
           DataColumn(
               label: Text(
             "Period",
             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
           )),
           DataColumn(
               label: Text(
             "Amount",
             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
           )),
         ],
         rows: widget.datalist
             .map((data) => DataRow(cells: [
                   DataCell(
                     Text(data.month,
                         style: const TextStyle(
                             fontSize: 26, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                   ),
                   DataCell(
                     Text(data.price.toString(),
                         style: const TextStyle(
                             fontSize: 26, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                   ),
                 ]))
             .toList(),
       )));     }}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c58UG.png) api call twice

api call fires twice the first one bring response. second one is send request without header and receive error. i am using jsontodart.in to create class. Help me execute future builder in clean way

Answer (score 1):

For the non data problem :

Remove your getter :

```
get datalist => null;
```

declare a datalist variable in your Datatable class:

```
class Dataclass extends StatefulWidget {
  Dataclass({Key? key, required List<UnpaidDetails> this.datalist})
      : super(key: key);

  List<UnpaidDetails> datalist;
```

And read it from your state with

```
rows: widget.datalist
```

instead of

```
rows: datalist
```

And for your second call. You don't have to make a call in initstate. So you can delete your initstate method and change your future builder like this :

```
        body: FutureBuilder(
        future: unpaid(),
```

Comment: Thanks for your support . full code updated. still api fires twice and getting error implement correction in dataclass